# How do I disable rate limiting on my local Horizon server?

Tags: horizon, rate-limiting

The [docker quickstart](https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon#stellar-quickstart-docker-image) doesn't tell me how to disable rate limiting.

Also, the [Go SDK which we are using seems to have a rate limit function](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/init_web.go#L182) as well... I'm guessing that is just enforcing the rate limit it gets from Horizon.

so presumably if I disable rate limiting in Horizon, I'm good.

Is that a startup parameter or a config file to disable rate limiting?

my local horizon is set just like the public horizon:

```
stk@steve-kelp:~$ curl -i "https://localhost:8000"
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
stk@steve-kelp:~$ curl -i "http://localhost:8000"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Type: application/hal+json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Origin
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 101
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 100
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either environment variables which you can read from a config file by using a start script [(like this one comes along with debian/ubuntu packages)](https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/stellar-horizon-utils/stellar-horizon-cmd) or command line params.

To disable rate limiting you have to set `PER_HOUR_RATE_LIMIT=0` (config/env) or add `--per-hour-rate-limit 0` (command line).

For docker a configuration file should be located in /opt/stellar/horizon/etc/horizon.env, see
https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon#customizing-configurations.

There is a good overview of all options in `horizon help`:

```
stellar@l:/root$ stellar-horizon help
client-facing api server for the stellar network

Usage:
  horizon [flags]
  horizon [command]

Available Commands:
  db          commands to manage horizon's postgres db
  serve       run horizon server
  version     print horizon version

Flags:
      --connection-timeout int         defines the timeout of connection after which 504 response will be sent or stream will be closed, if Horizon is behind a load balancer with idle connection timeout, this should be set to a few seconds less that idle timeout (default 55)
      --db-url string                  horizon postgres database to connect with
      --enable-asset-stats /assets     enables asset stats during the ingestion and expose /assets endpoint, Enabling it has a negative impact on CPU
      --friendbot-url string           friendbot service to redirect to
      --history-retention-count uint   the minimum number of ledgers to maintain within horizon's history tables.  0 signifies an unlimited number of ledgers will be retained
      --history-stale-threshold uint   the maximum number of ledgers the history db is allowed to be out of date from the connected stellar-core db before horizon considers history stale
      --ingest                         causes this horizon process to ingest data from stellar-core into horizon's db
      --log-file string                name of the file where logs will be saved (leave empty to send logs to stdout)
      --log-level string               minimum log severity (debug, info, warn, error) to log (default "info")
      --loggly-tag string              Tag to be added to every loggly log event (default "horizon")
      --loggly-token string            Loggly token, used to configure log forwarding to loggly
      --max-db-connections int         max db connections (per DB), may need to be increased when responses are slow but DB CPU is normal (default 20)
      --max-path-length /paths         the maximum number of assets on the path in /paths endpoint (default 4)
      --network-passphrase string      Override the network passphrase
      --per-hour-rate-limit int        max count of requests allowed in a one hour period, by remote ip address (default 3600)
      --port uint                      tcp port to listen on for http requests (default 8000)
      --rate-limit-redis-key string    redis key for storing rate limit data, useful when deploying a cluster of Horizons, ignored when redis-url is empty
      --redis-url string               redis to connect with, for rate limiting
      --sentry-dsn string              Sentry URL to which panics and errors should be reported
      --skip-cursor-update             causes the ingester to skip reporting the last imported ledger state to stellar-core
      --sse-update-frequency int       defines how often streams should check if there's a new ledger (in seconds), may need to increase in case of big number of streams (default 5)
      --stellar-core-db-url string     stellar-core postgres database to connect with
      --stellar-core-url string        stellar-core to connect with (for http commands)
      --tls-cert string                TLS certificate file to use for securing connections to horizon
      --tls-key string                 TLS private key file to use for securing connections to horizon

Use "horizon [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

Comment: whoa! now that explains the rate limit problem. It is based on an hour window, not 100 per second which you get from looking at the HTTP: headers. So the HTTP response headers have TWO values for rate limiting: the number of seconds of the window and the # transaction in the window. The config is only one number and it is per hour. Huh?!?