# Too many open files from horizon

Tags: horizon

After sending few request to horizon or running horizon for sometime, getting too many open files:443 error. Then I have restarted the horizon then above error is removed.Is there any configuration I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's 443 or do you confuse the number with the https port? However horizon has a rate limit by default, so a "429 Too Many Requests" response could be likely (=> [How do I disable rate limiting on my local Horizon server?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2222/how-do-i-disable-rate-limiting-on-my-local-horizon-server)). Otherwise some more details on where exactly you get the errors (horizon logs? client sdk something?) and what exactly is the message.

Comment: Actually horizon is running on 443 as SSL is configured. The error is not "429 Too Many Requests". Its saying too many open files unable to load localhost:11627 stellar core.